# Robot Framework : Error while connecting Oracle Database through DatabaseLibrary

Tags: robotframework

I tried to connect to Oracle Database through Robot framework, i am getting error.

In Database Library documention given the syntax as below:

```
# explicitly specifies all db property values                       
Connect To Database     psycopg2    my_db   postgres    s3cr3t  tiger.foobar.com    5432
```

[Link to DatabaseLibrary](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.6/DatabaseLibrary.html)

I used the same in my code as below:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Trouble Ticket Test Cases
Library     Selenium2Library
Library     DatabaseLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Connect To Database

*** Keywords ***
Connect To Database
    Connect To Database cx_Oracle    MTNIODC48    ABL_DBOBJECTS    abill_2808_prod    172.20.22.48    1521
```

I ran and got the below error:
Keyword 'DatabaseLibrary.Connect To Database' expected 4 arguments, got 6.

Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks
Sarada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using -

```
Connect to Database using Custom Params  cx_Oracle  '${ABL_DBOBJECTS}/${abill_2808_prod}@172.20.22.48:1521/${MTNIODC48}'
```

Also, you can add the dependency like

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ..${/}..${/}lib${/}databaselibrary-0.6${/}DatabaseLibrary${/}
```

& download the DatabaseLibrary [Here](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/)

Comment: Hi Hemant, i am getting the following error `No keyword with name 'Connect to Database using Custom Params' found.'

Comment: Please check documentation here.. http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html#Connect%20To%20Database%20Using%20Custom%20Params

Also make sure that you are using right indentation.

Comment: @SaradaAkurathi thats becasue you copied the keyword's name. It using capital in every word, like `Connect To Database Using Custom Params` check the corresponding documentation: 

http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html#Connect%20To%20Database%20Using%20Custom%20Params

Comment: Thanks Hemanth and Richard, it worked. I need one more small help, to give this DatabaseLibrary as dependancy in Eclipse Maven project, can you please tell me how to give, otherwise how to make it work under maven also. I searched there is no Maven Dependency for this DatabaseLibrary(Python).

Comment: Adding dependencies & download path for DatabaseLibrary is edited in answer. Thank you.

Comment: @HemantKulkarni, i am very sorry , i didn't understand the solution you have proposed. how to download the DatabaseLibrary. Actually i have download through `pip install robotframework-databaselibrary` command and i am able to see the folder `D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robotframework_databaselibrary-0.8.1.dist-info` and not `databaselibrary-0.6${/}DatabaseLibrary' can you please help me

Comment: That was relative path for library I have. You can have it accordingly as per your computer path. My complete file looks like-

*** Settings ***
Library           ..${/}..${/}lib${/}databaselibrary-0.6${/}DatabaseLibrary${/}


*** Variables ***

*** Keywords ***
Query Database
    [Arguments]  ${sql}
    Connect to Database using Custom Params  cx_Oracle  '${lsuser}/${lspasswd}@172.16.225.40:1521/${dbschema}'
    @{result} =   Query   ${sql}
    Disconnect From Database
   [Return]   ${result}

Comment: Hi Hemant, I am very sorry to bother you for each and every thing, now the issue came when running the Connect To Database Using Custom Params is that `ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle' I have installed cx_Oracle from the site `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.2.1' and it is the path as `D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cx_Oracle-5.2.1-py2.7.egg-info' and `D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cx_Oracle.pyd` i tried to import from both but no use, can you please help. I didnt see any folder with cx_Oracle like DatabaseLibrary with keywords

Comment: I am not very sure about this, but you can take help from previous issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908055/python-import-cx-oracle-importerror-no-module-named-cx-oracle-error-is-thown

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and This is the solution which I found

Step 1: Install Oracle instant client (32 bit) ( I'm using instantclient_18_3, You don't have to install cx_oracle seperately )

Step 2: Install Operating System Literary and the Database Library for Robot and import it

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DatabaseLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem
```

Then in your robot script, Add The following variable and make sure it's with the test cases (NOT in an external resource file)

```
*** Variables ***
${DB_CONNECT_STRING}    'DB_USERNAME/DB_PASSWORD@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=YOUR_DB_OR_HOST)(PORT=YOUR_PORT))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=YOUR_SID)))'
```

Then you can use the following keywords to set the environment variables and to run queries

```
*** Keywords ***
Connect To DB
    [Arguments]    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING_VALUE}
    Set Environment Variable    PATH    PATH_TO_YOUR_INSTANT_CLIENT\\instantclient_18_3
    Set Global Variable    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING_VALUE}
    #Connect to DB
    connect to database using custom params    cx_Oracle    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING_VALUE}

Run Query and log results
    [Arguments]    ${QUERY_TO_EXECUTE}
    Set Global Variable    ${QUERY_TO_EXECUTE}
    ${queryResults}    Query    ${QUERY_TO_EXECUTE}
    log to console    ${queryResults}

Disconnect From DB
    #Disconnect from DB
    disconnect from database
```

Finally, in your test case run it like this

```
*** Test Cases ***
Get Sysdate Test
    [Tags]    DBConnect
    Connect To DB    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}
    Run Query and log results    SELECT sysdate from Dual
```

This should work fine for you