# PyCharm not detecting cx_Oracle module

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, cx-oracle

Python interpreter is taking module name as `cx-Oracle` rather than `cx_Oracle`. I am not able to import cx_Oracle. It says no module as such. however `import cx_Oracle` works when entered in IDLE.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: import cx\_Oracle ImportError: No module named cx\_Oracle error is thown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908055/python-import-cx-oracle-importerror-no-module-named-cx-oracle-error-is-thown)

Comment: I'm having the same issue and can't find a solution. Have you ever solved this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with PyPI and setuptools. PyPI accepts the name with the underscore but setuptools does not. It adjusts all names by turning underscores into dashes. Here are some links that help explain the situation:

Question:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2011-August/017935.html

Answer:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2011-August/017936.html

I just tried PyCharm and imported cx_Oracle just fine. In the package list it does show up as cx-Oracle -- but that shouldn't prevent you from using it!

Comment: i am unable to use it. It is still giving error of module not found.

Comment: Are you trying within the Python Console found in PyCharm? Or something else? If you are using the Python Console in PyCharm, what error are you getting?