# cx_Oracle connection issue from python

Tags: python, oracle

Hi I am getting below error when trying to connect to Oracle from python.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\OraConnect.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
ImportError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908055/python-import-cx-oracle-importerror-no-module-named-cx-oracle-error-is-thown/10207688

Comment: Here is the direct link to the [cx_Oracle installation instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html).